# How to display text in a TextFlow

Tags: java, javafx, display

I am trying to display text in TextFlow in JavaFX. It is not displaying anything and I am unsure why this is not working. I added a TextFlowid to my views and am trying to add some text in the controller.

Controller:

```
public class LoggingTabController
{

   @FXML
    private TextFlow tflow;
  @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {

        Text text1 = new Text("asd");
        Text text2 = new Text("Some Text");
        tflow.getChildren().addAll(text1, text2);
  }
}
```

Views:

```
<GridPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" percentWidth="100.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="535.0" minHeight="484.0" prefHeight="515.0" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="0.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="0.0" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <TabPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <HBox minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="Button_Update" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="77.0" prefWidth="134.0" text="Select All" />
            <Button fx:id="Button_SelectAll" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="77.0" prefWidth="167.0" text="Copy to Clipboard" />
            <Button fx:id="Button_Update1" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="77.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Save Log to File" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="449.0">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="567.0" prefWidth="511.0">
               <children>
          <TextFlow id="tFlow" fx:id="tFlow" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="567.0" prefWidth="511.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Any ideas why it is not displaying anything?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `TextFlow` in the controller? You have already created one in the FXML file. You don't display the new one that you create in the controller anywhere.

Comment: @James_D Didn't realize I didn't have to create two of them. How would I be able to display text in the controller then?

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. You don't have to create two of them. Are you intending to use the text flow you created in FXML, or are you wanting to create a brand new one?

Comment: Gotcha. I am wanting to use the one in the FXML.

Comment: So you need to give it an `fx:id` and have a corresponding`@FXML`-annotated field in the controller. See this [SO documentation example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers/5125/example-fxml#t=201704032217029293321)

Comment: @James_D I have tried replicating what is in that doc, but am still having trouble. I updated my post with what I tried. Any ideas??

Comment: The `fx:id` needs to match the field name. You have `fx:id="tFlow"` but the field name is `tflow`.

Comment: boom! You are a genius :) @James_D